# jquery 1.3 not(:first) problem in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

i have 3 div tags of same class,

```
<div class="redc">
<p>sdfs</p>
</div>

<div class="redc">
<p>sdfs</p>
</div>

<div class="redc">
<p>sdfs</p>
</div>
```

to select div other than first ,`$(".redc:not(:first)")` works fine in mozilla,but not in IE

Please suggest any alternative for IE

Note: vesion jquery 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the first item, you can use the [slice function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=slice):

```
$('.redc').slice(1);
```